# Change color of helptext component salesforce

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am using help-text component in my lightning web component.

```
<lightning-helptext content="Size (width x height x lenght)"></lightning-helptext>
```

[image]

How can I change the tooltip background and text color?

I added this to my css but it does not work

```
.THIS .slds-popover_tooltip, 
.THIS .slds-popover--tooltip {
    background: #FF0000; /* background color */
    color: #444444; /* text color */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can access the component's children like this and according to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-helptext/documentation) you cannot apply custom styling for the tooltip content in lightning-helptext using

```
--sds-c-tooltip-*
```

You can only change the styling of the button

```
<lightning-helptext content="Size (width x height x lenght)" class="newColor"></lightning-helptext>
```

css

```
.newColor{
    --sds-c-button-color-background: #FF0000;
}
```

Additionally you could try something like [that](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tooltips/)

```
<div style="padding-left:2rem;padding-top:5rem;position:relative">
        <button class="tooltip-btn slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button slds-button_icon" aria-describedby="help"
            aria-disabled="true" title="Help">
            <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#info"></use>
            </svg>
            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Test</span>
        </button>
        <div class="slds-popover slds-popover_tooltip slds-nubbin_bottom-left slds-hide" role="tooltip" id="help"
            style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:15px">
            <div class="slds-popover__body">
                Test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
.tooltip-btn:hover + .slds-popover.slds-popover_tooltip.slds-hide {
    display : block!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to change the background of the tooltip, not the button. I try to use this --sds-c-tooltip-color-background but it does not work. Could you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ah ok I cannot use that --sds-c-tooltip-* class. So there is no way that I can change the background color right?

Comment: How can I write a custom tooltip using https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tooltips/? I copy and paste the template but the tooltip always shows

Comment: I editied the answer, you need to add the slds-hide class on the popover and then some css for the button on hover.